# How to embed src file in a wiki in Gitlab/Github?

Tags: gitlab, wiki

I have a doc folder in my project (in Gitlab) which contains documentation generated using jsdoc. This documentation is generated at build time.

What I want to do now is to embed the resulting index.html file in a wiki, so that on each build, the wiki is automatically updated.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [clone your GLitab wiki locally](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/wiki/index.html#adding-and-editing-wiki-pages-locally).

That means, after each local build, you can add one step to your build in order to modify and embed the content of the generate files (here the resulting `index.html`), then add, commit and push back to your GitLab wiki.

As the [OP tigermarques](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3688552/tigermarques) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097526/how-to-embed-src-file-in-a-wiki-in-gitlab-github/47123184#comment81264451_47123184):

> The only extra thing I had to do was to rename the `.html` file to either `.md` or `.txt` so that Gitlab would show it on the Wiki page list.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! The only extra thing I had to do was rename the .html file to either .md or .txt so that Gitlab would should it on the Wiki page list. Works like a charm!

Comment: @tigermarques Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.